# Configure UrlReplacer to only work for specific IP addresses

Tags: url-routing

Is there any way that [UrlReplacer](http://www.motobit.com/help/url-replacer-rewriter/iis-mod-rewrite.asp) can be configured so that the configuration page is only visible to certain IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the developer of this application, I've learned that there is no way to tie it down to a particular IP address.